# How to have two JPanels which always take up half the screen each, split horizontally?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

As described in the title. I've got two JPanels one on top of the other using a `BorderLayout()`.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class myForm(){
    public static void main(String[] args) {       
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("SingSong");
        myFrame.setLocation(100,100);
        myFrame.setSize(new Dimension(1024,800));
        myFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setBackground(new Color(0x00FF00FF));
        JPanel jp2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        jp2.setBackground(new Color(0x00000000));

        jp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,400));
        jp2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,400));
        jp2.setLocation(0, 512);

        myFrame.add(jp2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        myFrame.add(jp, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

They each take up half, but how can I go about setting it so that they always take up half the JFrame each, even when resized?
(P.S. I normally use better variable names, I just whipped up that as an SSCCE)

Comment: Use a single column `GridLayout`.

Comment: That snippet works if you bung it into a main method. For future reference do I need to include the main method, and class declaration?

Comment: Good work on the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  :)   +1

Comment: @AndrewThompson And now I know. I've fixed it up, hopefully that sweetens up your day sir :D xo

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the `GridLayout`

```
JFrame myFrame = new JFrame("SingSong");
myFrame.setLocation(100, 100);
myFrame.setSize(new Dimension(1024, 800));

GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, 1);
myFrame.setLayout(layout);

JPanel jp = new JPanel();
jp.setBackground(new Color(0x00FF00FF));

JPanel jp2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
jp2.setBackground(new Color(0x00000000));

myFrame.add(jp);
myFrame.add(jp2);

myFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I beat you by 5 secs. ;)  But +1.

Comment: Huhh?  You typed that entire answer in the 5 seconds between my comment and your answer?

Comment: Yeah, on a keyboard instead of the ipad :P  Actually, copy and paste

Answer (score 2):

when you setPreferredSize, the layout manager will make it so that both the panels are always 400 pixels tall. If you want the panels to always be half of the height of the frame, then don't set the preferred size. If that doesn't work, then you could always try setting the panels' height to `(myFrame.getSize().height) / 2` which will be half the height of the frame.